# Two dependencies with the same class

Tags: java, dependencies, classloader, netty

I currently am using two dependencies, one of which is being included in the jar file. Both of these dependencies are using netty; however, one is outdated. The second dependency is using the method 'Bootstrap#channelFactory()' which does not exist in the other dependencies version of netty. The outdated class is being loaded and I am getting a 'NoSuchMethodError' because the method does not exist in the outdated class. Does anyone have a solution?

EDIT: I am actually using 'Bukkit' which is a piece of software that lets you create a Minecraft server, and modify it using it's API. This is the first dependency. Bukkit uses netty and the other dependency which is being extracted into the jar file uses netty as well, but they are two different versions.

Comment: Are you using a dependency management tool such as maven or gradle? If so you could easily override the old import and just use the newer one.

Comment: I'm not. I am just adding them as dependencies in IntelliJ's project structure.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are wanting to call a methods from classes that have the same name (Let me know if you arent't!). As a last resort, you can call the method from the package directly if you need to use both classes. For example, let's say I have a class called "TestClass" in the package "net.test.program.one" and I have another class called "TestClass" in the package "net.test.program.two" you can call the class directly with net.test.program.two.TestClass or the other one net.test.program.one.TestClass as a last resort, hope this helps!

Code example:

```
private void doSomething() {
        // Call up-to-date one here
        net.test.program.one.TestClass.method();
        // Call out-dated one here
        net.test.program.two.TestClass.method();
}
```

Comment: Personally, I am not calling the method at all. One of my dependencies is using/attempting to use the method, but the wrong class is being loaded. The package and class names are the same so that wouldn't really be an option.

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry about that, I thought you were trying to call a method from two classes that had the same name ;-;